# why maven3 forbids RELEASE but allows [0,)?

Tags: java, maven, maven-2, maven-3

Well RELEASE and [0,) seems same to me.

If RELEASE is not safe, then [0,) is not safe too.

So what is the actual reason for deleating RELEASE?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Newer Maven versions try to encourage you to only use fixed versions (except for SNAPSHOT). While `RELEASE` was actually forbidden, version ranges are just considered bad practise.

I would not be surprised if they were removed from some future versions of Maven.